# What is the use of properties on Neo4J relationships?

Tags: neo4j

I am concerned I am not getting the full benefit from relations in Neo4J. While we use them to relate two nodes (of course), we rarely add properties to relationships and I feel like we're missing the bigger picture.

Consider a case where there's an EVENT and affected people.  We want confirmation from all people that they are informed of the event.

Here is what we do, and I think it is not great:

```
(e:EVENT)-[:NOTIFICATION]->(:EVENT_STATUS)-[:AFFECTED]->(a:PERSON)
```

Now it isn't so bad, because we need EVENTs and we already have PERSON. So we're adding the stuff that connects them. It works. However, the only purpose of EVENT_STATUS is to track a notification date and the PERSON's confirmation information.  The fact is, it feels like we're implementing a relational database structure.

Would it be wrong/suicidal to add the notification date and the PERSON's confirmation to the relation?

```
(e:EVENT)-[:INFORMED {notification_date: 123123123,
                      confirmation_date: 123123999,
                      confirmation_type: 'ATTENDING'}]->(a:PERSON)
```

Help me understand the *purpose* of properties on Relationships, please!

edit - English... is a skill.

Comment: It's not wrong nor suicidal to organize the information in the relationship using properties like you do. An alternative approach is to have multiple relationships between EVENT and PERSON nodes. This would make sense in that "informed" doesn't scream a RSVP relationship which your properties expose.

Answer (score 1):

Your proposed solution is just fine, since you are tracking different pieces of information about a particular type of  relationship between 2 nodes. This is exactly what relationship properties are for.

There is no need to add extra relationships and nodes, as you are now doing. Not only are you wasting resources, but your queries are made unnecessarily complex.